# O que esse código em assembly faz?

Tags: assembly

Estou brincando com o Cheat Engine em um joguinho de MMO RPG.

Acompanhando os valores do jogo na memória RAM através das funções do Cheat Engine, encontrei os endereços da memória onde são armazenados os valores de experiência do jogador. Mudá-los não dá resultado algum, além disso os valores só mudam nesses endereços alguns segundos depois do valor de experiência do jogador ser adicionado no jogo.

Porém, a Cheat Engine permite que você saiba o que é executado naquele endereço de memória, ou melhor, que código em assembly escreve o que nesse endereço.

Nesse caso, o código é esse:

```
01089EA7 - 8B 40 18  - mov eax,[eax+18]
01089EAA - 8D 4D FC  - lea ecx,[ebp-04]
01089EAD - 89 43 44  - mov [ebx+44],eax <<
01089EB0 - E8 62F2FFFF - call dro_client.exe+49117
01089EB5 - 8B 40 1C  - mov eax,[eax+1C]

EAX=000000C8
EBX=3230DAD0
ECX=0271EFB8
EDX=32BA0944
ESI=0271F098
EDI=00000001
ESP=0271EFA0
EBP=0271EFBC
EIP=01089EB0
```

Se alguém puder interpretar eu ficaria feliz. Mas saiba que é só uma brincadeira mesmo, não pretendo nada sério com isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é assembly x86 escrito na sintaxe da Intel. Existem muitas referências na internet para aprender o básico, não será dificil encontrar.

De maneira bem prática:

- `mov X,[Y]`: Escreve em X o que está na memoria de endereço Y.
- `mov [X],Y`: Escreve na memoria de endereço X o que está em Y.
- `lea X,[Y]`: Faz X = Y.
- `call AAA`: Chama a função no endereço AAA.